# LocalDate hasn't constructor... How can we create classes without constructor?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm reviewing Java 8 classes of the Time package and I have a doubt about the classes without constructor like LocalDate class.

If you create a Java class, this class will always have a default constructor, nevertheless LocalDate hasn't constructor, that is to say, you can't do this:

`LocalDate date = new LocalDate();`

If you do this, you will get a compile error "the constructor LocalDate() is undefined".

Why LocalDate hasn't a default constructor?

And the most important question... How can I create a class without constructor that only can be instanced calling static methods?

Thank you very much and regards.

Comment: None of the `java.time` classes have public constructors. What did you expect `new LocalDate()` to return? Similar to `new Date()`, i.e. todays date? Then call `LocalDate.now()`.

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question already. A *"constructor that only can be instantiated calling static methods"* is indeed all you need.

Comment: See also: [Why LocalDate, LocalTime and Stream objects use a factory method of() instead of a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38424319/5221149)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The typical pattern here is a class with only `private` or `package default` constructors, combined with a factory method that is either a public static method of the class or a method of an accompanying factory class. You get `LocalDate` objects from many static methods listed [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.now();
```

to create a LocalDate for now. There are more static methods to instantiate a LocalDate. The designers of the API decided to create static methods to instantiate LocalDates because they can have more clear names on what is actually instantiated (like "now()" above to create a LocalDate for the current date).

Answer (score 3):

> Why LocalDate hasn't a default constructor?

Because there is no "default value" for it to construct which makes sense. What would the year, month and day fields' values be in this case?

The default constructor is not the same thing as an explicit constructor with zero arguments. The default constructor is something added by the compiler, but *only* if you define no other constructors ([language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)). `LocalDate` has an explicit constructor, and thus it has no default constructor. That constructor is also private, so you can't invoke it directly.

*Effective Java* has a lengthy item (it is either Item 1 or Item 2, I forget which) about using static factory methods. One of the first advantages it cites is that they behave like *named constructors*.

It is clear, even without reading the Javadoc, that `LocalDate.now()` is going to return you a date which corresponds to "now". Whilst you could make a default constructor do the same, it would not be obvious.

Comment: I understand you, but if I create a class without constructor, I will always be able create an instance of this class with "new MyClass()" because this class will has a default constructor. Then, my question is: Why can I create a Java class without default constructor?

Comment: @brais1912 for the exact reason in the first sentence of my answer: because there is no (or there *may* not be a) default value that it makes sense to construct. The *default constructor* (as distinct from an explicitly declared no-args constructor) is a mere convenience, since all classes need at least one constructor, so one is added if you don't add one.

Comment: You say "since all classes need at least one constructor, so one is added if you don't add one.", then, why LocalDate hasn't constructors if theorically Java classes always has a default constructor? I repeat, How can I create a class without constructors if Java forces me to have a default constructor?

Comment: @brais1912 `LocalDate` has got a constructor, it is just not public, and takes more than zero arguments. Specifically, it has a constructor `private LocalDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`. And I repeat: "one is added **if you don't add one**".

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much!! Now I understood it, I didn't know LocalDate has a private constructor, I thought LocalDate hasn't any constructor. Thank you very much Andy!

Answer (score 0):

Java8 `DateTime` library give access to factory methods for creating objects of corresponding classes as opposed to constructors as it gives flexibility such as certain operations like parsing can be performed before the object is created. Also factory methods can have meaningful names as opposed to constructors. As mentioned in other answers you can use:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(); //creating LocalDate instance
```