# Why does LocalDateTime not have a String constructor?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date

I have recently run into the following error when trying to post JSON data via Spring MVC to a POJO that has a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) attribute:

```
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
```

To solve this error, I had to change my setter from

```
public void setToDate(LocalDateTime toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
}
```

to

```
public void setToDate(String toDate) {
    this.toDate = LocalDateTime.parse(toDate);
}
```

This left me with the question of why doesn't `LocalDateTime` have a `String` constructor as well as a static [`parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method?

Comment: You don't need to change your setter, you can keep your default setter with `LocalDateTime`. You can simply use `myobj.setToDate(LocalDateTime.parse("..."))`. There is no constructor `LocalDateTime(String)` because `String` have different usage. It's not an object for date/time

Comment: @KunLun The data is mapped from the `@ResponseBody` in a POST request. So I can't pass the parsed date as an argument I'm afraid.

Comment: I think is related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424319/why-localdate-localtime-and-stream-objects-use-a-factory-method-of-instead-of (Look the reference to the book Effective Java)

Comment: @TobyCook because a String on it's own isn't enough. You would also need to know how it is formatted (for instance)

Answer (score 0):

(Nearly) none of the classes in `java.time` has any constructor at all, at least no public constructors. You can create an instance of these classes only by calling one of the static factory methods (with `~.parse()` being one of them).

Of course, this was a design decision when creating the `java.time` packages.

One reason for that decision could be that there is a rule according to that constructors should not throw exceptions, for some reasons I can't currently remember. But it should be obvious that constructing an instance of `LocalDateTime` from an arbitrary String allows for a lot of possible errors.