# LocalTime class is a final class but no constructor given, why?

Tags: java, constructor, new-operator, final

Can we have a constructor of a final class. I know that String class have constructor, but I am looking specifically at `LocalTime` class of `java.time` package. It does not show any constructor. But one can get object of this class through static method like `LocalTime.now()`. Why we don't have a constructor as simple as new(). Please throw light on this.

Comment: It has a constructor, but it's just private. With factory methods exposed, there's no need for the constructor to be available to other classes.

Comment: Because there is no default value that it makes sense to construct.

Comment: It uses static initializer.

Comment: This answer to related question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424937

Comment: Thank you  ernest_k, Rohit Kavathekar & Slaw

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple [advantages of factory methods](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/02/5-difference-between-constructor-and-factory-method-in-java.html#axzz6ccPM3C5i) over constructor.

1. Readable Names
2. Polymorphism (Any instance of sub class can be
   returned)
3. Coupling (Factory methods promote the idea of coding using
   Interface then implementation which results in more flexible code,
   but constructor ties your code to a particular implementation)
4. Caching (returning cached object rather than creating always new
   one)

Although all these advantages are not valid in this context, but creating multiple constructors make it unclear for the users to understand, which constructor has what details. Case where multiple constructor are possible replacing it with static factory methods make the object construction for the user more readable. And user can use correct initialization method by looking at the name.

Even **Effective Java - from Joshua Bloch** mentions about it very well. Considering all these advantages, it's valid to replace constructor with static initializer.

Comment: Thanks notescrew, I appreciate your explanation.